# Resource Handler bypassing security Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a springboot app that requires a custom resource handler where it stores and retrieves files apart from the default one, which i got up and running with this;

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry

    .addResourceHandler("/data/**")
    .addResourceLocations(resourceLocation)

    .setCachePeriod(864000)
      .resourceChain(true)
      .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver())
      ;


}
```

My app has multiple authorities that should have access to the certain parts of the data resource location eg. /data/keys/** should only be accessible by ADMINISTRATOR authority, /data/client/** only by client, /data/public/** by everyone.

i tried accomplishing this functionality with this part of code:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/data/**").authorizeRequests()
            // ADMIN file restriction
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
}
```

(I am testing security here on all data/**)

Now with this code, any request to the /data/** matcher is not authenticated, and anyone can access it no matter what i do. But somehow i can apply security to the default resource handler and that one works just fine if i try to restrict.

Does anyone know how to bypass this problem?

Many Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

After some investigation and trying out options with different type of files and authorities I've noticed that there might be a bug with this. 
I was playing with these file extentions .txt .html and a file without extention.
EG.

1. Opened a new browser, tried downloading test.txt and test1 ---> Access denied
2. Logged in with different authority than ADMINISTRATOR, tried downloading test.txt and test1 ----> Forbidden
3. Logged in as ADMINISTRATOR, downloaded both
4. Logged out
5. Tried downloading without credentials test.txt ---> Access denied; test1 ----> Downloaded
6. Logged in with different authority than ADMINISTRATOR test.txt ---> Forbidden; test1 ----> Downloaded

I think there is a bug with files without any extention, has anyone had any experience like this or knows why is this happening? Thanks

Comment: You could use a configuration similar to the one described here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authorize-requests

So, basically antMatcher for /data/keys/** with hasRole "ADMIN", antMatcher for /data/client/** with hasRole "CLIENT" etc.

Comment: Unable to insert it as lambda for some reason, tried doing this with no effect:
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/data/keys/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMINISTRATOR").anyRequest().authenticated();
I think that this has something to do with Resource handler bypassing everything if declared

Comment: Try using as .antMatchers("/data/keys/**").hasRole("ADMIN"). This will work if the logged in user has a role of "ADMIN". Spring Security Documentation link - https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/helloworld-boot.html

Comment: Doesn't work :(

Comment: the order of matching is important: `http.antMatchers("/data/keys/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
       .antMatchers("/data/client/**").hasRole("CLIENT")
       .antMatchers("/data/**").authenticated()`